# send the content of a ListviewItem to a TextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I am having problem in affecting to a TextBlock "TxtChoisie" the Content (Nom/Categorie) of a ListViewItem in a universal app,this is my code:

xaml code:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="#575855" FontSize="18 "  x:Name="TxtChoisie" />
    <ListView x:Name="listme" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Single" ItemClick="listme_ItemClick">
                                            <ListViewItem>
                                            <TextBlock Text="Nom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"  Foreground="#727271" />
                                            </ListViewItem>
                                            <ListViewItem>
                                                <TextBlock Text="Categorie" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"  Foreground="#727271" />
                                            </ListViewItem>
                                        </ListView>
```

code behind:

```
 private void listme_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var myClickedItem = e.ClickedItem.ToString(); ;
            TxtChoisie.Text = myClickedItem;
        }
```

what I get in my TextBlock is not the Content(like Categorie or Nom)
thanks for Help

Comment: What do you get in your TextBlock?

Comment: I get this string Sir "Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock"

Comment: when I debugging the Variable ClickedItem has the Text property that contains the selected Item Text :/

Comment: but I can't put TxtChoisie.Text = myClickedItem.Text;

Comment: I believe you need to set SelectionMode to None if IsItemClickEnabled is True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClickedItem` is an object. [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemclickeventargs.clickeditem.aspx)

You will need to convert it to a `TextBlock` and then read the `Text` property to get the right value:

```
var myClickedItem = ((TextBlock)e.ClickedItem).Text;
TxtChoisie.Text = myClickedItem;
```

You can miss this local variable out:

```
TxtChoisie.Text = ((TextBlock)e.ClickedItem).Text;
```

You should also check that the clicked item is a TextBlock before casting:

```
var myClickedItem = e.ClickedItem as TextBlock;
if (myClickedItem != null)
{
    TxtChoisie.Text = myClickedItem.Text;
}
```

or in C# 6 syntax:

```
TxtChoisie.Text = myClickedItem?.Text;
```